# Angular Firebase on mobile

Tags: angular, firebase, mobile

I built an Angular app that uses Firebase to store music albums (a wantlist) that works great on PC. No errors. When I pull the app up on mobile, it doesn't add anything to the storage in Firebase like it does on PC.

I know I have no code listed here to go off of. But I was just wondering if anyone has experienced this issue with Firebase, mobile... and I'm using a Bootstrap Angular modal to submit the data in question -  so I'm wondering if that could be the main problem. Does anyone know if there's a compatibility issue between these things. It delivers the data great on PC, but not on mobile. Particularly an iPhone 12. I can't find anything online about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Code? Logs? Anything that might help us understand what you are doing

Comment: Check their issue list https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue